IntelliJ Mysql Connection fails with "unknown_ca"
I made a docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.1'

services:
  mysql1:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password1
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql1-data:/var/lib/mysql

  mysql2:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password2
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql2-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysql1-data:
  mysql2-data:

which I ran and verified that I am able to connection with MYSQL command line client:
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -P3307 -ppassword1
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -P3308 -ppassword2

Then I created connections to the two MYSQL instances in IntelliJ. Then I clicked "test connection" in IntelliJ which failed with "unknown_ca". I verified the password was correct. As is the case with UI stuff, I don't know where to look to even begin to understand where the problem might be.

As my project deals with a lot of DBs I was hoping to use this IntelliJ window but apparently UI fails again and CLIs are the only reliable thing in our world.

Please attach screenshot from "SSL/SSH" tab of your DB settings. Also please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after reproducing the issue to check connection log.
